# How to create socket (domain socket) in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sockets

netcat & socat are other possibilities to do this, but is there any other better way as C programming have socket() bind() accept()?

Comment: By definition, no. Unless bind etc are provided as keywords in the shell, which they aren't, what you ask is impossible, as the only alternative is executing some program, whose socket(s) will disappear when it exits.

Comment: EJP & Laszlo Valko, thanks for the reply. I am going to use netcat (for Linux) and nc (for Mac) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, for programming tasks with such a complexity, shell scripts would not be recommended, even if there was support for sockets. I'd use Python or Perl, if I wanted to sockets in a script.

Both of them has libraries with socket support at different levels (low-level, C-like socket operations, or high-level, easy-to-use object-oriented networking support).

[Python networking](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html), [Python support for Internet protocols](http://docs.python.org/2/library/internet.html), [Perl socket functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions-by-cat.html#Low-level-socket-functions), [Perl socket library](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html)